# How does Ignite Zero Deployment work

Tags: java, ignite

Ignite has a fantastic 'Zero Deployment' feature and its workflow is as follows:

1. Ignite will check if class is available on local classpath (i.e. if
   it was loaded at system startup), and if it was, it will be
   returned. No class loading from a peer node will take place in this
   case.
2. If class is not locally available, then a request will be sent to
   the originating node to provide class definition. Originating node
   will send class byte-code definition and the class will be loaded on
   the worker node. This happens only once per class - once class
   definition is loaded on a node, it will never have to be loaded
   again.

And I write an sample code:

```
Collection<Long> broadcastResult = compute.broadcast(new IgniteCallable<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    long result = 0;
                    Long total = getTotal(10);
                    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                        LOGGER.info("adding {}, result {}", i, (result = result + i));
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            });
...
    public static Long getTotal(long total) {
            LOGGER.info("Total:{}", total);
            return total;
        }
```

And it works fine, Remote Node printed `add xxx` log ten times. But I am really wondering how?

1. How does Ignite know `My IgniteCallable Instance` needs
   `getTotal(long total)` method?
2. How does Ignite transfer `My IgniteCallable Instance's Byte Code` to
   Remote node when i only give him `My IgniteCallable Instance's
   Reference` rather than a class file?

Please help me out, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering on your questions.

1. Initially your `IgniteCallable` gets serialized and sent over the wire. When the JVM starts executing it and comes to the point when `getTotal` is needed it will look for a class definition that has this method and if the JVM doesn't find it locally it will pre-load it from the origination node as well.
2. Everything is simple. Basically we just take `Class` of you instance using a call like `igniteCalllable.getClass()` serialize it and send over the wire. If you take a look at `Class` object source code you will see that its `Serializable`.

Comment: Small correction. `getTotal` method is static, so the instance of the enclosing class is not serialized (and probably doesn't even exist). But the byte code for this class will be loaded by the server node's class loader when it needs it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I figured out some points  but not totally clear. When a node sends the `IgniteCallable` instance to remote node to be executed, it is serialized in general way. the key point is remote node has a special classloader. during deserializing process. Classloader's `resolve()` method will be called and all dependent class will be passed to classloader and classloader will try to load class from local, if local has, or broadcast a `Class Fetch` request and get from other node. But I am not total sure or clear about it.

Comment: Your understanding is almost fully correct. The only addition I have is that a dependent class, which methods or instances are somehow used in the source of your `IgniteCallable`, will be loaded only when a JVM comes to the point of execution when the dependent class is needed.

Comment: Thanks, @dmagda. i went through ignite project code, However i didn't find any kind of  `Classloader` detailed it's work.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!